# How to fix the unauthorized axios/react response

Tags: reactjs, axios

Unauthorized axios/react response

Hi there friends, I'm trying to connect to an api through Axios and React but an error message appears saying that I don't have access here's my action:

```
import {SHOW_PROMOTIONS} from './action-types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const showPromo = () => async dispatch =>{
    const url= 'https://payment-promotions-dev.travelit.com.ar/api/promotions/packages/';
    let config = {
        "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtdW5kaWdlYSIsImp0aSI6ImQ0ODE1ZDk4LTJlYmQtNDRjYS04NGViLTU4N2JjNTY5NzgzZCIsImlhdCI6MTU1NTM0ODUwMCwibm9tYnJlIjoiTXVuZGlnZWEiLCJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbklkIjoiMSIsInBhaXNJZCI6IjEiLCJ0aXBvQXBsaWNhY2lvbklkIjoiMSIsImFjdGl2YSI6IlRydWUiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTUzNDg1MDAsImV4cCI6MTU1NTk1MzMwMCwiaXNzIjoiVHJhdmVsSVQiLCJhdWQiOiJUcmF2ZWxJVCJ9.o4Tv6Cw1Mj5xmHIQQ7abm6k6Ean6s6eQ3IDEkHY6Frk"
    };

    axios.get('http://<host>:<port>/<path>', url,config)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
        })

    const respuesta = await axios.get(url,config);
    dispatch({
        type: SHOW_PROMOTIONS,
        payload: respuesta.data
    })
}
```

When I execute the component, this error appears: (See following image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ODO.jpg)

The token is at it's respective header, I don't seem to recognize wat I'm doing wrong.

I even tried to do the request with Postman and it throughs 200: (See image2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUlul.jpg)

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: you need to add the authorization token type so it's like so: `"Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciO..."`

Comment: @AmrAly I tried to use `"Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciO...` and the error prevales

Comment: You aren't actually setting `headers` currently by passing `config`. You need to specify a `headers` property on the `config` object and put the desired headers into that property. `const config = { headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", // ... } };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently aren't actually specifying `headers` for the request. You would need to add `headers` property to the `config` object and put the desired headers into that property. Also, as the comments have you stated, you would also need to specify the `type` for the `Authorization` request headers, such as `Bearer`:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtdW5kaWdlYSIsImp0aSI6ImQ0ODE1ZDk4LTJlYmQtNDRjYS04NGViLTU4N2JjNTY5NzgzZCIsImlhdCI6MTU1NTM0ODUwMCwibm9tYnJlIjoiTXVuZGlnZWEiLCJhcHBsaWNhdGlvbklkIjoiMSIsInBhaXNJZCI6IjEiLCJ0aXBvQXBsaWNhY2lvbklkIjoiMSIsImFjdGl2YSI6IlRydWUiLCJuYmYiOjE1NTUzNDg1MDAsImV4cCI6MTU1NTk1MzMwMCwiaXNzIjoiVHJhdmVsSVQiLCJhdWQiOiJUcmF2ZWxJVCJ9.o4Tv6Cw1Mj5xmHIQQ7abm6k6Ean6s6eQ3IDEkHY6Frk"
  }
};
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hi there Alex! I specified the header as you suggested me. And now this is what happens: https://imgur.com/kAStN6q Should I check something else?

Comment: That's a step in the right direction. It sounds like this answer helped move it forward. That would be different error regarding CORS. There are many questions and answers about enabling/configuring CORS depending on your server platform. https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I really appreciated your help Alex. Thank you! I'll be posting another question if needed, also, I'll look into the link you gave me, you helped me find the way :D